# Как запустить golang через root и затем сбросить права?

Tags: golang

Например, запустить сервер на 80 порту и затем сбросить права, чтобы программа выполнялась не через root

Comment: Вот как это сделать на Си: [Dropping root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357737). Возможно, таким же образом получится сделать через `cgo`.

Answer (score 1):

Сброс прав осуществляется через системные функции операционной системы.

Для работы с системными функциями в golang есть библиотека syscall.

Для macosx следующий код работает:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    myGid := 100
    myUid := 100

    if syscall.Getuid() == 0 {
        if err := syscall.Setgid(myGid); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error setting gid as %d: %s", myGid, err)
        }
        if err := syscall.Setuid(myUid); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error setting uid as %d: %s", myUid, err)
        }
    }

    log.Printf("My uid is %d, my gid is %d", syscall.Getuid(), syscall.Getgid())
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если запустить компилятор через sudo будет ошибка. Error setting gid as 100: operation not supported
exit status 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893635/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-uid-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5-golang-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Да. Попробовал на Linux - с версии 1.4 не работает. Работает только на macos x. На гитхабе открытый баг по этому поводу https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435

Answer (score 1):

Проверил, что работает на macos x и linux x64 при помощи вызова CGO.
Похоже, что в go испортили Setgid в syscall linux.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

/*
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
*/
import (
    "C"
)

func main() {

    myGid := 100
    myUid := 100

    if syscall.Getuid() == 0 {

        cerr, errno := C.setgid(C.gid_t(myGid))
        if cerr != 0 {
            log.Fatalln("Error setting gid as %d, error: %d", myGid, errno)
        }
        cerr, errno = C.setuid(C.uid_t(myUid))
        if cerr != 0 {
            log.Fatalln("Error setting UID as %d due to error:", myUid, errno)
        }
    }
    log.Printf("My uid is %d, my gid is %d", syscall.Getuid(), syscall.Getgid())
}
```