# Не изменяется UID в рантайме golang, как изменить?

Tags: linux, golang

```
func main() {

    // Выводит 0
    fmt.Println(syscall.Getgid())


    err := syscall.Setuid(1000)
    if err != nil {
        // Выводит operation not supported
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}
```

Запускаю через sudo -E go run /path/...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### tl;dr

В Go `Setuid ()` для Linux не реализован. Нужно использовать другие механизмы понижения привилегий.

#### Немного деталей

Дело в том, что в Linux потоки реализованы, как «облегчённые» процессы, и *системный вызов* `setuid ()` устанавливает владельца только текущего потока, а соответствие поведению, описанному в POSIX обеспечивает обёртка над этим вызовом в glibc, которая посылает сигнал всем остальным потокам, вызывающий обработчик, который делает аналогичный системный вызов из каждого потока.

Go в своей реализации не использует (и не хочет использовать) libc, а работает напрямую с системными вызовами, поэтому появился [баг 1435](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435), в результате которого id менялся только у вызывающего потока, а не у всего процесса. Хорошего решения пока ни кто не придумал, поэтому с Go-1.4 `Setuid ()` заменён на заглушку, просто возвращающую ошибку.

Comment: Отвратительно, что в пакете syscall этой информации нет. "Нужно использовать другие механизмы понижения привилегий", а какие есть еще варианты? cap_net_bind_service=+ep тоже не работает.

Comment: @АлександрРезов, `cap_net_bind_service` должен работать — скорей всего ты просто не умеешь его готовить... если root нужен только ради порта, то это будет самый простой способ… ещё вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248866/golang-dropping-privileges-v1-7) ещё высказана идея, открыть сокет, а потом, не закрывая его, создать новый процесс (при создании процесса setuid нормально отрабатывает)… гипотетически работать должно, на вскидку API вызовов хватает, но это, пожалуй, хак и скорей всего при попытке реализовать наткнёшься на десяток-другой граблей и какие-то будут фатальными…

Answer (score 0):

Проверил, что работает на macos x и linux x64 при помощи вызова CGO.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

/*
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
*/
import (
    "C"
)

func main() {

    myGid := 100
    myUid := 100

    if syscall.Getuid() == 0 {

        cerr, errno := C.setgid(C.gid_t(myGid))
        if cerr != 0 {
            log.Fatalln("Error setting gid as %d, error: %d", myGid, errno)
        }
        cerr, errno = C.setuid(C.uid_t(myUid))
        if cerr != 0 {
            log.Fatalln("Error setting UID as %d due to error:", myUid, errno)
        }
    }
    log.Printf("My uid is %d, my gid is %d", syscall.Getuid(), syscall.Getgid())
}
```

Если нужен для портов, то `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep имяexe`