# Процессы и нити в Линукс

Tags: linux, многопоточность, процесс

Чем отличаются процессы и нити в Линукс? В книге Дмитрия Кетова я прочитал, что процесс состоит из нитей. Но ведь у нитей тоже есть PID и свойства, как у обычных процессов, и порождать другие нити они тоже могут.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Определение

Раз уж говорим о *nix системах, то не лишним будет опираться на определения POSIX (вольный перевод):

> [*Thread*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_393) (досл. *нить*, она же *поток*<sup>¹</sup>) — это один из *потоков выполнения* (*flow control*) в составе процесса. У каждой нити есть свой *thread ID*, приоритет и политика планировщика, `errno`, своё обособленное хранилище формата ключ/значение, и необходимые ресурсы, чтобы поддерживать *поток выполнения*. Любой объект, адрес которого может определить нить будет доступен всем нитям данного процесса, включая, но не ограничиваясь, статическими переменными, памятью, полученным посредством `malloc()`, другим областям памяти, к которым возможен прямой доступ по адресу, и автоматическим переменным.
>
> [*Процесс*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_289) — адресное пространство с одной или более нитью, исполняющейся в контексте оного, а также необходимые ресурсы для данных нитей. 
>    *Замечание:* многие системные ресурсы разделяются (используются совместно) разными нитями одного процесса. В том числе различные идентификаторы (PID, PPID, PGID, SSID, различные SUID'ы и SGID'ы), текущий рабочий каталог, корневой каталог, umask и файловые дескрипторы.

Отсюда вырисовываются следующие ассоциации ресурсов...

У процесса есть:

- Адресное пространство (включая код, а также статические и динамические данные программы)
- Одна или более нить
- Таблица файловых дескрипторов
- Другие системные ресурсы и идентификаторы

При этом у каждой нити процесса также есть:

- Поток выполнения, на практике это значит:

  - Свой стек и, как следствие, свои локальные переменные.
  - Свои регистры процессора
- ID нити
- Приоритет в планировщике
- `errno` и, возможно, некоторые другие переменные локальные для нити.

#### Особенности реализации потоков в Linux.

Фактически, *потоки* в Linux реализованы, как «легковесные процессы». Другими словами со стороны ядра linux нет чёткого разграничения между оными: все они представляются в ядре, как *задачи* [`task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L584), при этом, например, `task->mm` указывает на дескриптор адресного пространства ([`mm_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L354)), а `task->files` на таблицу файловых дескрипторов ([`files_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L48)) и для потоков одного процесса оба эти указателя будут просто указывать на один объект. ИМХО прежде всего это сделано в силу исторических причин, хотя такая реализация и не лишена своей красоты.

И всё бы ничего, но это породило просто невообразимую терминологическую кашу. Например, со стороны пользовательского пространства идентификатор процесса (то что возвращает `getpid()`, он должен быть одинаковый для всех потоков процесса) называется PID; но на стороне ядра под `pid`'ом подразумевается идентификатор задачи, а вызов `getpid()` возвращает то что называется `tgid` (*thread group ID*, *ID группы потоков*). Но при этом через `/proc` экспортируется информация именно в терминах ядра.

Также такая реализация предполагает определённые ухищрения, частично на стороне ядра, частично на стороне пользовательского пространства, например, *системный вызов* `setuid(2)` в linux устанавливает только EUID потока, поэтому приходится прибегать к сложным манипуляциям в обёртке в libc, чтобы добиться поведения соответствующего POSIX и, как следствие, возникают проблемы с реализацией этой функции в языках независимых от Си, например Rust или [Go](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893635/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-uid-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5-golang-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

---

> Но ведь у нитей тоже есть PID и свойства, как у обычных процессов,

Не совсем так: единственное, что у них есть — это приоритет и политика в планировщике... всё остальное — баги и/или особенности реализации.

> и порождать другие нити они тоже могут.

Да, но здесь стоит заметить, что в отличии от порождения процесса, «родителем» новой нити становится исходный процесс, а не тот что породил нить.

---

<sup>¹я предпочитаю термин «*поток*», но дабы не разгребать терминологическую путаницу с *flow* буду использовать «*нить*» в данном разделе</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Термин «поток» (thread, нить) является краткой формой
Поток выполнения процесса.

Поток выполнения — это последовательность исполняемых
команд, которые можно запланировать для запуска на ЦП.

Потоки также имеют некоторое состояние и хранят некоторые
локальные переменные.

Нити процесса разделяют его программный код, глобальные
переменные и системные ресурсы, но каждая нить имеет свои
программный счетчик, содержимое регистров и стек

Процесс — совокупность взаимодействующих нитей и
выделенных ему ресурсов.

Вот картинка для наглядности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]