# Модуль, процесс и поток

Tags: системное-программирование

Только начал разбираться с этими терминами, вроде бы уяснил отличия, но какая у них взаимосвязь?
С процессом и потоком вроде понимаю, что связь прямая, процесс не может существовать без потока, поток входит в набор ресурсов процесса. А как к процессу относятся модули?
В документации майкрософт нашёл небольшое пояснение: "Модуль процесса представляет a.dll или exe-файл, который загружается в определенный процесс"
Если кто может, пожалуйста объясните подробнее связь между этими вещами (и в случае чего, укажите на мои ошибки в выше описанном объяснении).

Comment: Модуль, это машинные команды (и данные), которые исполняются в потоках процесса

Comment: Про потоки/процессы применительно к POSIX уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015819/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%9b%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81/1016046#1016046). В других ОС семантика примерно такая же, хотя могут быть мелкие отличия в том, кому-какие ресурсы принадлежат.

Comment: А *модуль*, вообще говоря, — это просто функционально законченный фрагмент программы. Общепринятого значения в области архитектуры ОС у этого термина нет. POSIX им не оперирует. А в windows под ним обычно понимается, как и написано, «отдельный файл (exe или dll) с исполняемым кодом, который загружен в процесс». Не знаю, есть ли там какое-то более строгое определение.