# Как при реализации системных вызовов open/write/read... для символьного устройства модуля ядра, получить pid делающего системный вызов процесса?

Tags: linux, c, unix, kernel, ядро

Как при реализации системных вызовов  open/write/read... для символьного устройства модуля ядра, получить pid делающего системный вызов процесса?

```
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

вот сигнатура write в структуре file_operations. Как из передаваемых аргументов получить pid процесса, делающего системный вызов ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В любой точке ядра текущую задачу можно получить через глобальную переменную<sup>¹</sup> `current`, которая представляет собой указатель на [`task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.2/source/include/linux/sched.h#L728). Соответственно её PID<sup>²</sup> можно получить как `current->pid`.

---

<sup>¹ В современных версиях ядра, технически, это обычно уже не переменная, а макрос, вызывающий функцию.</sup>
<sup>² Это то число, которое на стороне ядра называется PID, оно [может отличаться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015819/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%81/1016046#1016046) от того, что под этим понимает POSIX.</sup>